# Netcat does not receive an response over tor

Tags: tor

I configured Tor Hidden Service to forward from port 5400 to 127.0.0.1:1234. Then i restared tor and I got hostname. Now I run `nc -l 1234` and i visit the website and I receive a GET request. Now I wanted to send other data so on the other computer I run `echo test | torify nc -w 2 -z MY_hidden_service_address port`. When I run it my server just quits and does not print **test**. But if it quits then it means that it receives a response, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the connection gets properly open and closed (thats why your nc quits) but there is no data transferred. This is because torify does not expect you to just pipe data into it I suppose.
To check maybe try using netcat without torify (`nc -v -X5 -x localhost:9050 <server> <port>`) or get rid of echo and your pipe and try using nc interactively.

Comment: I tried this command but it says that parameter -X5 and -x does not exist

Comment: OK I think i found a problem. Netcat command pointed to ncat not netcat. Now it works. Thanks for help